# Trigger "click" en Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

Saludos necesito ayuda ya que estoy intentando ejecutar el trigger "click" en un elemento del DOM, he intentado lo siguiente:

```
let content2:any= document.getElementById('activarOrdenes');
content2.triggerHandler('click')
```

pero me sale un error:
"content2.triggerHandler is not a function"
espero me ayuden porque he estado mucho tiempo con este error

Comment: Loque dijo carlosdag28, es lo mejor pare la practica puedes probar esta solucion, en ngOnInit añade esto document.getElementById('mydiv')?.addEventListener('click', this.myFunc); y fuera escribe la funciona que ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usarlo de esta manera:

```html
<div class="class1 class2" (click)="onDivClick()"></div>
```

Cuando se pulse sobre ese div, se llamará a la funcion `onDivClick()` de tu componente

Answer (score 0):

lo pude solucionar de la siguiente forma:

```
let content2:HTMLElement= document.getElementById('activarOrdenes') as HTMLElement;
content2.click();
```

y listo solucionado...